# Merging multiple string arrays into one

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to merge three string arrays into a new one.

```
OUTPUT
ARRAY1 = towers
ARRAY2 = films
ARRAY3 = high
array is: towersfilmshighw
```

The thing is, the three arrays are successfully merged into a new array but there are extra and random characters added - in this case, a `w`.

I am not allowed to use pointers to merge the arrays.

Can anyone explain why the extra characters are there?
Because after this, I need to delete the duplicate characters and it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char array1[10], array2[10], array3[10], AllChar[50];
  int lenghtOfArray1, lenghtOfArray2, lenghtOfArray3, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, z = 0;

  printf("Array 1");
  gets(array1);
  printf("Array 2");
  gets(array2);
  printf("Array 3");
  gets(array3);

  lenghtOfArray1 = strlen(array1);
  lenghtOfArray2 = strlen(array2);
  lenghtOfArray3 = strlen(array3);

  if (!(lenghtOfArray1 <= 8 && lenghtOfArray2 <= 8 && lenghtOfArray3 <= 8)) {
    printf("The length of all words must bigger than or equal to eight\n");
  } else {
    while (j < lenghtOfArray1) {
      AllChar[j] = array1[i];
      i++;
      j++;
    }
    while (j < (lenghtOfArray2 + lenghtOfArray1)) {
      AllChar[j] = array2[k];
      k++;
      j++;
    }
    while (j < (lenghtOfArray1 + lenghtOfArray2 + lenghtOfArray3)) {
      AllChar[j] = array3[z];
      z++;
      j++;
    }

    printf("array is :");
    for (i = 0; i < (lenghtOfArray1 + lenghtOfArray2 + lenghtOfArray3); i++) {
      puts(&AllChar[i]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to add a null-terminating character (`'\0'`) to `AllChar`

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but since this seems to be for an assignment: you misspelled `length` in your variable names.

Comment: @fenceop I didn't notice that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize `AllChar` array, so it has garbage in every one of its elements.
Just replace the last piece of garbage with a `'\0'`

```
AllChar[j] = 0; // after the last update loop
```

or initialize the array (all of it; there's no partial initialization in C) in the first place

```
char AllChar[50] = "";
```

Comment: I can't Vote Up your answer .. But seriously Thank you, it totally slipped my mind.

Comment: No, that is the definition statement because it includes the `char` type. The `50` is the length of the array, not an element. `char a[50]; // uninitialized` ... `char b[50] = ""; // initialized` ... `b[49] = 0; // change one element of b`